# MySQL: Check one month or one year in future inside query

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have one auto-billing process what I need to automate via cron job. I want to made query where I can check in database is payment ready for  autobilling or no.

Here is table:

```
id  user_id     client_id   payment_id                      save_details    auto_billing    price   plan    created     active
3   1           1           PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    0               1               10      M       1484576988  2
7   1           1           PAY-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy    1               1               10      M       1484945652  1
4   1           2           PAY-ssssssssssssssssssssssss    0               1               10      M       1484594351  1
6   1           15          PAY-tttttttttttttttttttttttt    0               1               96      Y       1484615360  1
```

And my current query:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(`p`.`auto_billing`) AS `total`
FROM
     `payment` `p`
WHERE
     `p`.`auto_billing` = 1
AND
     `p`.`active` = 1
```

QUESTION IS:

How I can check if `plan` is `M` and add on `created` +1 month or `Y` and add on `created` +1 year to lather I can check via PHP current timestamp and start auto-billing?

I need to somehow transform `created` field into future expected time of 1 year of month depends on `plan` variable.

I would like to change ths complete table but system allready have a arround 7000 records and don't want to messup something.

Thanks!

Comment: Use CASE and DATE_ADD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `DATE_ADD` and conditional expression:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(IF(plan='M', DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) from payment
```

This sql will add to created appropriate interval.

Comment: well, looks a little overcomplicated)

Comment: is not, is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). Try queries with WHERE clauses like this one:

```
      FROM_UNIXTIME(created)  <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

or this one:

```
      FROM_UNIXTIME(created)  <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```